# Simple dependency-free HTML/JS serverless image gallery that does not try to pre-process my images

Tags: javascript, html, images, gallery

I want a HTML/JS image gallery generator that "scans" images in a directory and creates a HTML file with a "viewer" for the pictures.

### Use case

Before:

```
DSC02241.JPG  DSC02293.JPG  DSC02348.JPG  
DSC02242.JPG  DSC02296.JPG  DSC02349.JPG  
DSC02243.JPG  DSC02297.JPG  DSC02350.JPG
```

`create_gallery *.JPG > gallery.html`

After:

```
gallery.html
DSC02241.JPG  DSC02293.JPG  DSC02348.JPG  
DSC02242.JPG  DSC02296.JPG  DSC02349.JPG  
DSC02243.JPG  DSC02297.JPG  DSC02350.JPG
```

Actually the images may be not JPGs, but some unknown format.

### Crude prototype

```
echo '<html><body>' > gallery.html
for i in *.JPG; do echo "<img src=\"$i\"/>" >> gallery.html
echo '</body></html>' >> gallery.html
```

### Requirements

1. Not linking into Internet for dependencies;
2. Minimum number of required files and minimum overall size;
3. Not loading all gigabytes of images into memory at once;
4. Basic prev/next/fullscreen/slideshow buttons, thumbnails with pages, etc.;
5. No pre-processing of images. Images (including thumbnails) should be just used in appropriate `<img>` inside the viewer. It should not stop on unknown file type (I want to use [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) with the appropriate JS decoder).

Comment: Found [sigal](http://sigal.readthedocs.org), but it requires config file and it messes with images and maybe even JPG-specific (and I want to integrate the gallery with [PBG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) JS decoder)

Comment: Looked at `igal2` - Thumbnails seem to be implemented using separate files and it tries to interpret input images (hence `Can't find any image files in directory .`) instead of just indexing them.

Comment: All those galleries seem to _love_ JPG...

Comment: [PhotoFloat](http://git.zx2c4.com/PhotoFloat/about/) looks promising... But by default it still generates JPG thumbnails I want to avoid.